# Uploading multiple "documents" to IrisCouch from a JSON file

Tags: json, node.js, couchdb

I have a large dataset in JSON format that I would like to upload to IrisCouchDB.

I found the following instructions: http://kxepal.iriscouch.com/docs/1.3/api/database/common.html

But I am a newbie and it also seems to be for a single JSON document. Im afraid I will just create one huge entry and not multiple documents entries which is what I want.

I have NodeJS but I don't have Cradle. Will I need it in order to perform this function? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, no! That's bad idea to reference on docs at my Iris host - that's was preview dev build. Please follow the official docs: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/index.html

To update multiple document's you need to use [/db/_bulk_docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-bulk-docs) resource:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/db/_bulk_docs \
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '{"docs":[{"name":"Yoda"}, {"name":"Han Solo"}, {"name":"Leia"}]}'
```

So you see the format of data you should send to CouchDB? Now it's all depending from you JSON file format. If whole file is an array of objects: just wrap his content into `{"docs":..}` object. If not: you have to write some small library to convert this file data into the required format.